# Convert Range of Days to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate

I am working at parsing an RSS, and due to different factors, have had to resort to NSScanner & had to strip dates out of an NSString and Convert to dates.  This has worked pretty well, except for one small thing.  If the range of dates stays on the same day, it works just fine to return an NSDate as the start date.  However, if the NSString shows different days, the NSDate returns as null.  What I need is to convert

> Thu Sep 28, 2013 to Fri Sep 29, 2013

into an NSDate of

> Thu Sep 28, 2013

Also, not all entries have a range, some are just Thu Sep 28, 2013...so it limits what I can really do to strip out everything after to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cut the optional second part of the string using something like this:

```
NSString *firstPart = [[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" to "] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, using an appropriately set up `NSDateFormatter`, you can do the conversion to `NSDate`.